# Conditionally matching numbers from string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a string of numbers formated as so:

> 24_1_1_1_1_1_12_1_1_13_1_1

*Underscores being spaces*

I need to grab 3 numbers. The first number in this case `24`, then the number after the following two `1's` which in this case it is a `1`. Then after another two `1's` would be `12`. I have tried numerous `sed`, `awk` and `grep` solutions to get the answer but the issue is that any of the needed 3 numbers could be 1,2 or 3 digits long.

So in this example I would need the bolded numbers.

> **24**_1_1_**1**_1_1_**12**_1_1_13_1_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set $IFS to `_` and split the string into an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
string=24_1_1_1_1_1_12_1_1_13_1_1
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=_
ar=($string)
IFS=$OIFS
echo ${ar[0]} ${ar[3]} ${ar[6]}
```

Comment: This just prints the fields that match the example.

Comment: @sudo_O: It depends on how you interpret the specification: "the number after the following two 1's".

Comment: @user2152271 can you clarify if just wanted to print certain fields *(in this case 1,4,7)* or if the field numbers aren't fixed and really do depending if two `1`s have been seen?

Comment: @choroba: I also had IFS set to `_` first but then I noticed in the post it says: "Underscores being spaces".

Comment: @Scrutinizer: Hm, I did not notice it. Strange how it might work then :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into an array, then just iterate over the array:

```
str="24_1_1_1_1_1_12_1_1_13_1_1"
IFS="_" read -ra numbers <<< "$str"
results=( ${numbers[0]} )
take_next=0
for n in "${numbers[@]:1}"; do
    if (( take_next == 2 )); then
        results+=( $n )
        take_next=0
    elif (( n == 1 )); then
        (( take_next++ ))
    else
        take_next=0
    fi
    (( ${#results[@]} == 3 )) && break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following `awk` one-liner to print the first field then every field after two ones:

```
$ awk 'NR==1||c==2{print;c=0;next}$1==1{c++}' RS=_ file
24
1
12
13
```

If you want exit after a certain number of matches *(e.g 3)*:

```
$ awk 'NR==1||c==2{print;c=0;m++;next}$1==1{c++}m==3{exit}' RS=_ file
24
1
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Using read:

```
read a x x b x x c x <<< "$str"
```

-

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
24
1
12
```

Comment: @user2152271: I did not use underscore as the field terminator, because in your post is says: "Underscores being spaces", otherwise the read statement can be prepended like so: `IFS=_ read ....`